# Extracting list of filenames, including ones with blanks, from find

Tags: bash, find

I'd like to do something with each file of some type in a particular directory. I've written, in a bash script,

```
HANDIN_FILES=`find . -type f -printf "%f\n" | head -20 `
for i in $HANDIN_FILES
do
  echo $i
done
```

as a kind of first version. This works great if there are no blanks in any filename. If there is a file `silly name.txt`, then `i` ends up being first `silly` and then `name.txt`, which is not what I want at all.

I know that I could put all the `do ... done` stuff in a `-exec` option in the `find` command, but I'd like to preserve the list of files in a shell variable for later use as well. Can someone suggest a quick fix that'll cause `i` to have the value `silly name.txt` on one iteration through the loop?

Comment: See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `bash` 4.4+:

```
readarray -td '' files < <(find . -type f -print0 | head -zn 20)
for i in "${files[@]}"; do
  something with "$i"
done
```

With earlier bash versions:

```
files=()
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
  files+=("$file")
done < <(find . -print0 | head -zn 20)

for i...
```

Here, it's simpler to use `zsh`:

```
files=(**/*(D.[1,20]))
for i ($files) something with $i
```

(at least the file list will be sorted so the *first 20* makes more sense)

See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) for other ways to process (or not) `find`'s output.

Comment: Thanks; that not only solved my problem, but reading the linked stuff provided a bit of education as well!